# How do I control the starting text position within a multicols environment?

Tags: multicol

The text starting position varies wildly in the multicols environment depending on font size.  If you pick a large font size, the text touches the top; but if you pick a small font size, the text sits very low.  This looks very lopsided.  How do I fix it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\newcommand{\m}{\begin{multicols}{2}
  \noindent
  this is a test\\
  this is a test\\
  this is a test\\
  this is a test
\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}
  \Huge\m
  \normalsize\m
  \tiny\m
\end{document}
```

[image: Ugly multicols]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use case for which `multicol`has been written is to mimic page creation as it normally happens execpt that instead of a single column several columns are produced. That means that on the top of each column `\topskip` is used to position the first line of the `multicols` environment.

`\topskip`is a register that is normally not changed throughout the document (even if the fontsize is changing in some places within the document). This is done so that the first line on a page is "usually" at the same position. The value for `\topskip`is typically defined by the class, i.e., if you specify `12pt` as an option to the class the default font size will be 12 points and the `\topskip` will be 12 points as well (while the `\baselineskip` will be something like `14.4pt`).

In your use case this may look a little strange, but as I said, the package wasn't written for this use case that the whole body of the environment would be in a different font size and if say you have a tiny font in the first line of the first column but a normal font in the second column then the `multicol` approach would make it come out right whereas with `\topskip`changing with the font size this would look rather uneven then.

Also, page breaking is an asynchronous operation, so the `\topskip` changed by a font size command within the text may happen at the wrong place as TeX decides to break earlier or later.

So one way to cater for your use case is to change `\topskip` for the time `multicols`is active, it is possible to do that inside the environment so that the old topskip value will be restored once the environment changes, e.g.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\newcommand{\m}[1]{\begin{multicols}{2}
  #1\setlength\topskip{.7\baselineskip}%              set font and \topskip
  \noindent
  this is a test\\
  this is a test\\
  this is a test\\
  this is a test
\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}
  \m{\Huge}
  \m{\normalsize}
  \m{\tiny}
\end{document}
```

Now the font and the topskip value are only changes during the env body and you will get the following output:

[image]

Instead of making it 70% of the `\baselineskip` one could of course supply some explicit value or a different fraction. Less than 60% or so doesn't do anything because the characters will occupy that amout already.

Comment: Where does .7 come from?  Is it arbitrary? Or is \topskip typically set to .7\baselineskip?

Comment: @ConleyOwens it is just a guess here given what you were trying to achieve (making it a little bigger than lower case letters in most fonts). Traditionally \topskip is set to the nominal height of fonts, e.g 10pt with 10 point fonts whereas the default for \baselineskip is usually 20% more, e.g, 12pt in that case or 14.4pt for a 12pt font but depending on the font appearance one could or should fine-tune those.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where \topskip comes from, but the default is 12pt regardless of the font size.  Values less than .6\baselineskip seem to have no effect.  Larger values move the top higher.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}%

\newcommand{\m}{\topskip=.6\baselineskip
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \noindent
  this is a test\\
  this is a test\\
  this is a test\\
  this is a test
\end{multicols}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
  \Huge\m
  \normalsize\m
  \tiny\m
\end{document}
```

[image: topskip]

Comment: less than 60% makes \topskip smaller than then lowercase letter in which case it will not have any effect unless your line consists only of characters like period or comma. The value of \topskip comes from the 12pt option and is usually constant per document.